# unable to display apex:image from zip resource?

Tags: visualforce, force.com, static-resources

I have created 'download_images' static resource in salesforce , within that i have uploaded 'snaps.zip' file. After uploading , i have given path according to the salesforce docs
[https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_resources_reference.htm]
and generated url resource for accessing that image into the page.

```
<apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.images,'snaps/excel_login.png')}" />
```

here are the screenshots -->

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here it is not displaying any image . please suggest me how can i fetch images , dont say create url for resource because i have already created it .

Answer (score 3):

looks like the resource name is "download_images" but you have used "Images" in your VF code

Try this:

```
<apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.download_images,'snaps/excel_login.png')}" />
```